# Checkbox in Mediawiki syntax?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, syntax

Is there a way to insert an HTML checkbox in Mediawiki syntax?

`<input>` doesn't appear on their [list of blessed tags](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext), so I can't just insert it.

(FWIW, this is for a private documentation page which is a checklist, and I want to keep track of where I am as I go through it.)

Answer (score 7):

This is a quick way to add something like a checkbox if it fits you:

```
<span style="font-size:21px">☐</span>
```

Basically, it uses the 'hollow medium square' character "□" which is similar to a checkbox, but it is too small in its original form, so I had to apply some CSS to enlarge it.

To check it, replace it with a 'tick' mark. (✓, ✔, ☑, etc.)

Adjust the values to your needs.

Comment: Here's an slightly larger alternative to add to the answer. It's called 'white medium square': ◻

Comment: Don't know why this one is downvoted so low. ***IF*** you want a display-only checkbox and you don't have admin-access, this is the perfect/only solution.

Answer (score 2):

These tags are just free-form wiki text, like markdown on SO, and are provided for formatting but not input.  To add input html elements, or forms, use one of the MEdiawiki extensions, such as [semantic forms](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms) or [simple forms](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Simple_Forms).  Check [this URL](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Forms) out for an overview of how form content is handled in Mediawiki.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way to do it. It involves editing your mediawiki source, and depending which version you have, may not work just the same. This is for 1.15.3.

In the file sanitizer.php, near the end of the function `setupAttributeWhitelist()` add this line to the list

```
'input'      => array('type'),
```

Then find the function `removeHTMLtags` and add this to the end of the `$htmlsingle` (and for 1.19.4 and maybe an intermediate version, the  `$htmlsingleonly`) array:

```
, 'input'
```

Comment: I upgraded to 1.22.4 and it stopped working. I'd forgotten that I'd done this tweak, so I've just come across my own answer! I've also updated it.

Answer (score 0):

This renders a nice list of checkboxes:

```
== My Wiki Header ==

Here's an example checklist:
<html>
<input type="checkbox"> Item A.<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Item B.<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Item C.<br>
</html>
```

I don't recall having any special configuration on my wiki. Of course the checkboxes won't do anything, they're just for the looks.